# ionic run android app doesn't working without -l argument

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I use Ionic in order to create an application.

When I use the following command, the app working in my device :

```
ionic run android -l
```

This command start a web server on my computer, this web server will serve the app on device. The app depends on the webserver (so computer and device must be in the same network).

When I use the following command, the app doesn't work :

```
ionic run android
```

In fact, the app will display the first screen, but when I click on a button I get a blank screen. I can't use the console system (with **-c** argument) because without **-l** argument there is no webserver.

I want to debug my app without webserver.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Does it work in the browser?

Comment: Yes. I resolved my problem. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to GapDebug tool.

I used links like :

```
<a href="/#/home">
```

But this link point to no resource. We must remove first **/**.
So, I change all my links to this format :

```
<a href="#/home">
```

I hope it will help.